# How to stop a for-loop and make it work further?

Tags: python

I am new to python. And I hope that you can help me ;)

I have a data:

```
[('Senators', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'),
  ('believes', 'VBZ'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('possibilities', 'NNS'), ('of',
   'IN'), 
  ('every', 'DT'), ('boy', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('girl', 'NN'), ('.', '.'),
  ('The','DT'), 
  ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('sees', 'VBZ'), ('what', 'WP')......]
```

And I want to make a list in the list, that contains each a sentence, so that it looks like:

```
[ [('Senators', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'),
  ('believes', 'VBZ'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('possibilities', 'NNS'), ('of',
   'IN'), 
  ('every', 'DT'), ('boy', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('girl', 'NN')], [('The', 'DT'),
  ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('sees', 'VBZ'), ('what', 'WP')] ...]
```

But I have no idea how to do that :(  I have tried it with a help of a for loop

```
  for el in data:
     if el[0] != ('.' or '?' or '!'):   # finds only points((
     sentences.append(el)
```

How can I stop a loop when he finds a point? and how can I make it look further and write into a new list?

Comment: I can't really tell what you're looking for.  Perhaps you're asking what condition you can use to check a value against multiple values: if so, use `in` like this `if el[0] in ['.','?','!']:`.  Perhaps you're asking how to put a list in a list: `a = [1,2,3]; a = [a]`

Comment: The *second* element, the class, is *always* `.` for punctuation.

Comment: I have in one list the data that contains sentences and each word of a sentence is POS-tagged. I want to have each sentence in a separate list. So I want to have a large list, each element of it is a list with one sentence (without punctuation at the end of a sentece). Sorry for my english ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sentences = []
sentence = []

for word, code in data:
    sentence.append((word, code))
    if word in '.?!':
        sentences.append(sentence)
        sentence = []
```

If you don't want the point to be included in the sentences:

```
sentences = []
sentence = []

for word, code in data:
    if word in '.?!':
        sentences.append(sentence)
        sentence = []
    else:
        sentence.append((word, code))
```

Comment: Works great! But I don't want to have a point in a list ;( what should I do? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator:

```
def per_sentence(qualified):
    sentence = []
    for word, class_ in qualified:
        sentence.append((word, class_))
        if class_ == '.':
            yield sentence
            sentence = []
    if sentence:
        # yield tail
        yield sentence
```

Then produce a list with `list()`:

```
sentences = list(per_sentence(data))
```

Demo:

```
>>> data = [('Senators', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'),
...   ('believes', 'VBZ'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('possibilities', 'NNS'), ('of',
...    'IN'), 
...   ('every', 'DT'), ('boy', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('girl', 'NN'), ('.', '.'),
...   ('The','DT'), 
...   ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('sees', 'VBZ'), ('what', 'WP')]
>>> def per_sentence(qualified):
...     sentence = []
...     for word, class_ in qualified:
...         sentence.append((word, class_))
...         if class_ == '.':
...             yield sentence
...             sentence = []
...     if sentence:
...         # yield tail
...         yield sentence
... 
>>> list(per_sentence(data))
[[('Senators', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('a', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('believes', 'VBZ'), ('in', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('possibilities', 'NNS'), ('of', 'IN'), ('every', 'DT'), ('boy', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('girl', 'NN'), ('.', '.')], [('The', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('teacher', 'NN'), ('sees', 'VBZ'), ('what', 'WP')]]
```

Comment: It's perfect! But I don't want the signs ".?!" in a list ;(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the second element in each tuple of `data` is the word's class and will be `.` for all sentence terminators, try something like:

```
sentences = [[],]
for word in data:
    sentences[-1].append(word)
    if word[1] == '.':
        sentences.append([])
```

Tho, this will result in `sentences` containing an empty list at the end if the last sentences was properly terminated by an `.`-class element.